# what is the equivalent option in html for override of checkbox

Tags: html, perl

In cgi perl we use the override option for checkbox to retain its value in between form submission as shown below :

```
 my $chkbox_test = $qry->checkbox(
            -name    => "TEST",
            -label   => '',
            -checked => ‘ ‘,
            -override => 1

        );
```

Instead of above syntax, if I write plain html as shown below , how would I specify the override option

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="TEST" value="on" checked="">
```

Comment: `checked=""` is not HTML. The attribute should either be `checked` or `checked="checked"`

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

`override` dynamically generates a `checked` attribute depending on the input to the script.

HTML isn't a programming language. It can't read the input to the script or do anything with it.

You have to set the `value` and checked `attributes` **explicitly**.

Comment: But you could write HTML that had 'checked' set. But that'd be static.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation of the current version of CGI.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used):

> **HTML Generation functions should no longer be used**
>
> All HTML generation functions within CGI.pm are no longer being
>   maintained. Any issues, bugs, or patches will be rejected unless they
>   relate to fundamentally broken page rendering.
>
> The rationale for this is that the HTML generation functions of CGI.pm
>   are an obfuscation at best and a maintenance nightmare at worst. You
>   should be using a template engine for better separation of concerns.
>   See [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) for an example of using CGI.pm with the
>   [Template::Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Toolkit) module.
>
> These functions, and perldoc for them, will continue to exist in the
>   v4 releases of CGI.pm but may be deprecated (soft) in v5 and beyond.

So, really, don't do that :-)